# Select2-to-Tree on lxp:istbox but can not get selected values via SSJS?

Tags: xpages, jquery-select2, ssjs

I have the Select2-to-tree plugin https://github.com/clivezhg/select2-to-tree enabled for my xp:listbox:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "api.xsp/application?method=clientExecutives",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(response){
            x$("#{id:lbTest}").select2ToTree({treeData: {dataArr: eval(response)}});
        }, error : function(req, err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Here is how I set up the listbox:

```
<xp:listBox
    id="lbTest"
    value="#{sessionScope.clients}"
    multiple="true">
</xp:listBox>
```

When I try to read the values via SSJS initially it goes well:

```
<xp:button
    value="Label"
    id="button2">
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onclick"
    submit="true"
    refreshMode="norefresh">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("clients: " + sessionScope.get("clients"))}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

But as soon as I select a value the code seems to freeze and I get no print statement in the console. Note I do not get any error message or warning.

However when I read the selected value(s) in the listbox via csjs I get them:

```
<xp:button
    value="Label"
    id="button3">
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onclick"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert("Selected value is: "+x$("#{id:lbTest}").select2("val"));]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

What am I doing wrong?

alt perhaps I can set the sessionscope via csjs when the selection has changed for the listbox but that would require additional coding which I would like to avoid

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        x$("#{id:lbTest}").on("change", function(e) {

            //ToDO set sessionscope from csjs
        })      
    }
)
```

Comment: Seems you are wildly mixing SSJS and Client JS. I would suggest you define your server side control as text box and give it a css class that hides it.

Comment: Then do your select2tree completely client side and use csjs to update (or read) the values from/to the select2. This way your JS based on jquery and XPages JS based on Dojo don’t get in each other’s way

Comment: wildly mixing ssjs and csjs is something we do every day in any application in xpages to get the usability that we want. HOWEVER when I use a normal SELECT element the xpage does not get frozen so I assume the problem still relies with the selected value the xp:listbox recieves is not compatible what it expects to receive. other ssjs functions freeze when I select a value using the xp:listbox and transform it.

Comment: Don’t do that. You create frankenxode

Comment: You use multiple="true" in your listbox. I don't see any 'seperator' being used in the code where you initialize and start the Select2 code? The backend expects the values in correct format. Did you check the POST request after clicking the button with F12 in the browser, what was being sent to Domino?

Comment: how can I check the POST request?

Comment: Using developer tools in your browser (F12), check network network tab.